# How do I show there exists a unique solution in the following case?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

First I found the general solution for the equation:
$$ - y\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial x}} + x\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial y}} = 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbefMDPr
% garuavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garmWu51MyVXgaruWqVvNCPvMCG4uz
% 3bqee0evGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbb
% a9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXd
% bPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaiaaciWacmaadaGabiaaeaGaauaaaOqaai
% abgkHiTiaadMhadaWcaaqaaiabgkGi2kaadwhaaeaacqGHciITcaWG
% 4baaaiabgUcaRiaadIhadaWcaaqaaiabgkGi2kaadwhaaeaacqGHci
% ITcaWG5baaaiabg2da9iaaicdaaaa!472F!
$$
to be of the form:
$$u(x,y) = F({x^2} + {y^2})
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbefMDPr
% garuavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garmWu51MyVXgaruWqVvNCPvMCG4uz
% 3bqee0evGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbb
% a9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXd
% bPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaiaaciWacmaadaGabiaaeaGaauaaaOqaai
% aadwhacaGGOaGaamiEaiaacYcacaWG5bGaaiykaiabg2da9iaadAea
% caGGOaGaamiEamaaCaaaleqabaaeaaaaaaaaa8qacaaIYaaaaOWdai
% abgUcaRiaadMhadaahaaWcbeqaa8qacaaIYaaaaOWdaiaacMcaaaa!4537!
$$
so now I am required to find a unique solution that satisfies
the curve $$u(0,y) = {y^2}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbefMDPr
% garuavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garmWu51MyVXgaruWqVvNCPvMCG4uz
% 3bqee0evGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbb
% a9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXd
% bPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaiaaciWacmaadaGabiaaeaGaauaaaOqaai
% aadwhacaGGOaGaaGimaiaacYcacaWG5bGaaiykaiabg2da9iaadMha
% daahaaWcbeqaaabaaaaaaaaapeGaaGOmaaaaaaa!3FC6!
$$
The jaccobian, however, is zero for this parametrization when s=0.
I tried finding different parametrization, for which the condition does not fail, and have'nt been able to find one. 
Is there such a parametrization, or an alternative way, which isn't familiar to me to show that there is a unique solution?

edit: Please note: I am not asking how to find a solution that satisfies the above, but am asking how to show that the solution **unique** (existence can be shown simply by finding the solution).

Thnx

Comment: Hint: $y^2 = u(0,y) = F(0^2 + y^2)$. So what is $F$?

Comment: Hi thank you for that hint, however, that's not what I am asking..
I know how to find a solution. I want to know how to show it is unique, meaning there is no other solution (other than F), which satisfies the [PDE + condition]

Comment: Since you found the general solution, this means *every* solution has the form $u(x,y) = F(x^2 + y^2)$ for some function $F$. Since the boundary conditions uniquely specify $F$ on its domain (the positive reals), you have uniqueness.